# Laravel Validator custom message with "sometimes" rule

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-validation

This is a piece of my code, to validate a form input:

```
public function saveData(Request $request){
    $form_data = $request->all();

    $validation_fields = [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'last_name' => 'required',
        'cod_fisc' => 'sometimes|required|size:16',
        'p_iva' => 'sometimes|required|between:11,13'
    ];

    $errorMsgs = [
        'first_name.required' => 'Il campo Nome è obbligatorio.',
        'last_name.required' => 'Il campo Cognome/Ragione sociale è obbligatorio.',
        'cod_fisc.required' => 'Il campo Codice Fiscale deve contenere 16 caratteri',
        'p_iva.required' => 'Il campo Partita Iva deve contenere 11 o 13 caratteri',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($form_data, $validation_fields, $errorMsgs);

    ....
}
```

The whole project is written for Italian people, so all messages must be in Italian.
All works fine, but the two rules for `cod_fisc` and `p_iva`, that are binded to a "sometimes" rule, are displayed in English. My custom error messages are ignored.

Why?

Comment: It looks like a Laravel bug to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for your problem I have found this link: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sometimes-validator-with-custom-message

which contained a similar problem. The initial code was

```
$v = Validator::make(
                    $request->all(),
                    [ 'first_name' => 'required|max:60'],
                    ['first_name.required' => 'First name is really required, yo']
);

$v->sometimes('last_name', 'required|in:fake', function($input){
                    return true;
});
```

and the solution was

```
$v = Validator::make(
                    $request->all(),
                    [ 'first_name' => 'required|max:60'],
                    ['first_name.required' => 'First name is really required, yo'],
                    ['last_name.in' => 'Last name must be fake, too']
);

$v->sometimes('last_name', 'required|in:fake', function($input){
                    return true;
});
```

Apparently you may call the `sometimes` `function` on the result of `Validator::make` and pass the field name, the validator signature and a boolean `function`.

Comment: I tried that, do not work fine for me.
I found that it was easier to change the standard translation file inside resource.
/resources/lang/en/validation.php

Comment: @SimoneConti the problem with that is that you will need to keep that in mind whenever you upgrade your framework version.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but I don't plan to upgrade Laravel very soon.
In add, the other solution seem not to work for me. I'll try again, maybe.

Comment: @SimoneConti I understand your point that the solution I have presented was not feasible for you. Something's wrong and we do not know what. But if I were you, I would not close this case until a non-hacky solution is found. Not necessarily this one. For instance you could write to Laravel forums, or send a message to them.